# converting array into string with overflow in php

Tags: php, arrays, string, stack-overflow

I have simple code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
ini_set('html_errors', false);
$test = array();
$test = 'demo';
$test['55test'] = 'yay';
var_dump($test);
```

returns

```
 string(56) "demo                                                   y"
```

I know this is not proper way to convert string to array, but it seems that I've missed PHP docs about this case. 
Can anyone enlighten me regarding this?
Thanks

P.S. Tested in PHP 5.3.6-13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> String access and modification by character
>
> Characters within strings may be accessed and modified by specifying
>   the zero-based offset of the desired character after the string using
>   square array brackets, as in $str[42]. Think of a string as an array
>   of characters for this purpose. The functions substr() and
>   substr_replace() can be used when you want to extract or replace more
>   than 1 character.

Check the [string manual](http://jp.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Answer (score 1):

If you make this assignment:

```
$test['55'.'test'] = 'yay';
```

The following happen:

- Content of `[]` is converted to `int` and `(int)('55test')` gives `55`.
- Positions from `3` to `54` are not set. You are assigning to position `55` so they are all set to spaces.
- `$test[55] = 'yay'` results in `$test[55] === 'y'` because only one character of `'yay'` can be assigned to a single position in a string and the first one is selected.

Note there is no conversion of array to string. It is just that `string` can be accessed as `array`.

(this has been written before answer update)